# Connecting User to Profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

For my project (Django 1.5), I have two apps set up, one called accounts to handle authentication, and another called profiles that handles all profile manipulations. I've built a custom user model for the accounts app with the following set up:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.CharField()
    username = models.CharField
    is_staff...
```

And for the profile app:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    city = models.CharField()
    state = models....
```

I have things set up this way because I don't want the profiles instantiated when the user is created. I want it created on first sign-in.

I'm attempting to create a modelForm to help in creating the UserProfile. I'm a little befuddled about how I get the currently signed in user in order to save this to the OneToOneField. I know that is has something to do with the form's init method, but I've looked over the documentation and I can't seem to make out a clear solution. Please help!! So I have created a form like:

```
class BasicProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['foo']
```

My question: How do I input the user in my form? do i just use:

```
self.user = request.user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out..@Jay - thanks for setting me on course.

forms.py:

```
class FormaholicsAnon(forms.Form):
    name = forms.Char...  
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(FormaholicsAnon, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py:

```
# Make sure the current user is not anonymous
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    form = FormaholicsAnon(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) enabled, the request object carries a user attribute with it. So - yes, you can access it with request.user.

Please note that `request.user` can also be a `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser`. You'll have to make sure you are handling a 'real' user by calling `request.user.is_authenticated()` first.

Using exclude in ModelForms is generally a bad idea. It seems like a nice approach at first, but when your application gets bigger and you change your user model with this one hidden field you forgot to add in exclude.. ;)